# Reading Json with C# via HTTP Request

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem reading json from our local API.

This is a well known public json side which I also used for testing: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

This is my Json on my local API:
[image]

In C# I tried this:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string httpResponse = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testurl);
        WebResponse responseinger = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            await p.Get();
        }

        public async Task Get()
        {
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.WriteLine();

            string response2 = await client.GetStringAsync(testurl);
            Console.WriteLine(response2);
            Console.WriteLine();

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response2);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine();

           
            try
            {
                responseinger = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                responseinger = ex.Response;
            }

            reader = new StreamReader(responseinger.GetResponseStream());
            httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(reader);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(httpResponse);
            Console.WriteLine();

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var jsonwc = wc.DownloadString(testurl);
                Console.WriteLine(jsonwc);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

So I used different methods to get my json.

The json from the public json side works but my local not.

This is my output in the Console:
[image]

What can I do about it? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I suspect that your API is compressing the response, possibly without the request asking for that. You should look at the headers in both the request and the response to check that (particularly Accept-Encoding). It's hard to say more than that, really.

Comment: If I look in Postman. On the API URL Header at Content-encoding it says gzip could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe - that's okay if Postman sent an Accept-encoding header saying it supported gzip. But you're not interested in the Postman request/response - you're interested in the *C#* request/response. So look at the response headers, and ideally the request headers. Use Fiddler and/or Wireshark to inspect what's actually on the wire, if necessary. If the API is returning gzip-encoded data when the client didn't claim to support it, that's a problem with the API.

Comment: Ok I solved it. Thanks for your tip with Encoding. It has guided me in the right direction. Updated my question.

Comment: @Timebreaker900 Please do not update your question with the solution. Please leave a post and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Your right thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

My problem was gzip it compressed my json.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testurl);

    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    responseinger = req.GetResponse();

    reader = new StreamReader(responseinger.GetResponseStream());
    httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //Console.WriteLine(reader);
    //Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(httpResponse);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your accept header

```
    var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);              
    req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/ json");
    req.Method = "Get";
```